# How do you disable the auto generated pages /login and /logout using Spring SAML2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml, spring-security-saml2

I am using Spring Boot - 2.6.6 and Spring Security - 5.7.0-M2 with the spring-security-saml2-service-provider library to create a SAML service provider application. I followed Spring's sample project [Spring Security SAML2 Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/5.7.x/servlet/spring-boot/java/saml2/login-single-tenant/src/main/java/example/SecurityConfiguration.java) so my setup looks very similar.

I want to turn off the generated Login and Logout pages located on /login and /logout. The login page shows a link to each IDP configured and the logout page has a button that initiates the POST logout flow.

They appear to be created by Springs internal code - `Saml2LoginConfigurer.initDefaultLoginFilter` when `Saml2LoginConfigurer.loginPage` is not set or the `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` is active. Setting the `loginPage` variable only changes where the login page is displayed and breaks the metadata configuration from my Identity Provider: it does *not* turn the login page off. I had no success trying to turn off the `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter`.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample already includes everything needed to automatically redirect to the IDP (Okta in this case) and get redirected back. So the login and logout pages are only accessible if the URL is changed. Having said that, I can see why they are undesirable if they aren't being used.

To disable them, the simplest way is to provide an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. This disables the filters that generate the login and logout pages. For example:

```java
http.exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
    .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/saml2/authenticate/two"))
)
```

The reason this works is that it does explicitly what happens behind the scenes in `Sample2LoginConfigurer.init` while also disabling what happens in `Saml2LoginConfigurer.initDefaultLoginFilter`.

Comment: Thank you Steve. This worked but just want to clarify, the authentication entry point should equal to whatever you set the SAML2 authentication URL as. The default would be /saml2/authenticate/{registrationId}.

Comment: That’s correct, yes. Setting it that way will automatically trigger the login flow when the user is un-authenticated. This is the default in the configurer only when you have a single saml2 configuration. If you have more than one you can use this same trick to choose which is the default.